# List of tweets with clickable links, angular way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I'm displaying list of tweets as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="NewsFeedCntrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span ng-bind="item.text"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

angular.module('app').controller('NewsFeedCntrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  var id = 0;

  function update() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/_/modules/logs?name=twt&key=' + id
    }).success(function (data) {
          if (0 < data.length) {
              id = data[0].id;
          }

          setTimeout(function () {
              $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.items = data.concat($scope.items).slice(0, 1000);
              });
          }, 0);
      });
  }

  $scope.items = [ ];
  update();
  setInterval(update, 5000);
});
```

It displays the raw tweet data, which is OK. So now I want to decorate (probably filter) the data so it is displayed with clickable links, additional info, etc. How to do this in "angular way"?

Comment: what does individual data item look like?

Comment: Just a typical tweet with @something's, #something's, and links.

Comment: so nothing but text property? I don't play with their API much...been very long time. I'm sure you'll find plenty of regex string replace solutions for tweets though. Lots of jQuery plugins for them...would search there. Anything you do in angular would still be native  javascript  string manipulation to create new html

Comment: Ideally, I'm thinking about angular directive (or filter) that transform the given text tweet to nice-looking HTML widget.

Comment: understood...point of looking at other plugins is to gather regex methods used that you could pull into angular parser/filter. Might also come acrss some css you like at same time. Or even wrap another plugin in a directive